# tabexpansion doesn't fall through if overridden

Tags: autocomplete, powershell-2.0

The `tabexpansion` function only works partially when I override it like so:

```
function tabexpansion {
    param($line, $lastWord)

    if ($line -eq "hey ") {
        "you", "Joe"
    }
}
```

The custom completions work as expected, but now I only get the default autocomplete behavior for cmdlet names, not parameters. So *New-*<kbd>TAB</kbd> works fine, but *New-Alias -*<kbd>TAB</kbd> doesn't. How do I get the regular completions too after overriding `tabexpansion`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file name and cmdlet expansion is handled in the shell itself if the function doesn't do anything on those. Everything else, including static members, parameters to cmdlets, &c. is handled by the function. If you take a look at `Function:TabExpansion` there is quite a bit going on there you may want to keep if you want the other tab completion features to still work.